# Getting top n edges in a graph networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I have a directed multi-graph which with weights. The edge addition looks like

```
 g.add_edge(source_a,source_b, weight= some_Weight)
```

When the graph is built, I want to have edges only between top nodes between a node based on a weights. So if my graph is like

```
 1,2,0.5
 1,2,0.6
 1,2,0.4
 1,3,0.5
 ...
```

I want to only see top 2 edges between for each node. By top I mean, edges with top weights.
So the output will be something like

```
1,2,0.6
1,2,0.5
1,3,0.5
```

I am deleting rest of the edges. How do I do this using python/networkx?

Comment: Define Top Two: first two added? Two with highest weights leaving a particular node?

Comment: Won't it be easier to filter the data before building the graph? You can use something like `itertools.groupby` to do the messy work for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply iterate through the edges with a particular attribute:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.MultiGraph()
G.add_edge(1,2,weight=.5)
G.add_edge(1,2,weight=.6)
G.add_edge(1,2,weight=.4)
G.add_edge(1,3,weight=.5)

cutoff = .45

top = [edge for edge in G.edges_iter(data=True) 
       if edge[2]['weight'] > cutoff]

print top
```

This gives:

```
[(1, 2, {'weight': 0.5}), (1, 2, {'weight': 0.6}), (1, 3, {'weight': 0.5})]
```

From here it would be simple to create a new graph with only these edges.

```
G2 = nx.MultiGraph(top)
```